# CVXPY constraint: variable == 0 OR variable >= min

Tags: optimization, portfolio, cvxpy

I am trying to solve a portfolio optimisation problem with the constraint that weights can be either zero or at least `min` (a `Nx1` vector).

```py
import cvxpy as cp

w = cp.Variable(len(mu))
mins = np.ones(len(mu)) * 0.03
risk = cp.quad_form(w, S)

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(risk), 
                  [cp.sum(w) == 1, 
                   w >= 0,
                   w >= min OR w == 0  # pseudocode for my desired constraint]
```

This is equivalent to a constraint that the weights are `NOT 0 < w <= min`, but I cannot find a way to express this in CVXPY (I have googled things like "cvxpy OR constraint" to no avail).

It feels like I'm missing something obvious. Perhaps there is a solution involving some boolean vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called `w` being a **semi-continuous** variable. Most advanced solvers support this type of variable directly. As CVXPY does not understand semi-continuous variables, we can use binary variables δ ∈ {0,1} and form the constraints:

```
   δ⋅min ≤ w ≤ δ⋅max
```

where we can set `max=1`.

This makes the problem a MIQP (Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming) problem. This usually means that you need to use a high-end solver that supports this type of model.

Comment: Fantastic. That works well! I had tried something similar but without the maxes. No wonder that wasn't working :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Erwin's answer, this is the working code.

```py
import cvxpy as cp

w = cp.Variable(n)
mins = np.ones(n) * 0.03
maxs = np.ones(n)

risk = cp.quad_form(w, S)

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(risk), 
                  [cp.sum(w) == 1, 
                   w >= 0,
                   w >= cp.multiply(k, mins),
                   w <= cp.multiply(k, maxs)])
prob.solve(solver="ECOS_BB")
```

EDIT: changed `k @ mins` to `cp.multiply(k, mins)` as per comment

Comment: Warning, ECOS_BB is not very reliable. I have seen many problems with this solver. Fine for experimentation, but don't use it for production models.

Comment: Also, you may want to use elementwise multiplication instead of matrix multiplication..

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen noted re the correctness issues. For anything serious I'd try CPLEX or MOSEK, but ECOS_BB is the only one that comes pre-packaged with cvxpy.

Comment: Hi, could someone maybe explain what the k variable is in this scenario? I have am having a similar issue.